# How to configure Regular Expr. Extractor in While Controller to stop loop

Tags: jmeter

I configured a While Controller with following condition:

```sh
${__javaScript("${Status}" != "BatchId not found")}
```

and a Regular Expression Extractor:

Name of created variable:   `Status`

Regular Expression:  `(.+?)`

Template:            `$1$`

Match No.:           `1`

The request GetNextAsyncResponses in this While Controller checks the results of an async batch request until all results of this batch have been caught.

First I start the batch request and afterward the loop with the GetNextAsyncResponses request which checks if there are results of this batch.
When the batch request is finished I get a response body with string 'BatchID not found' which indicates that no more results are available.

The loop should stop GetNextAsyncResponses when the first response with the string 'BatchID not found' pops up.

But unfortunately, the loop never stops even if the string is shown after 4-5 loops.

I tried also following conditions which I found in similar cases without success.

```sh
${__jexl3("${BatchId}" != "BatchId not found")}
${__javaScript("${BatchId}".indexOf("BatchId not found") == -1,)}
```

I´m not sure what´s wrong ore missing here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating the regex as below capture:

[image]

And then setting While Controller condition to `${__jexl3("${Status}" == "NOT_FOUND")}`

Answer (score 0):

The variable used in the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) must match the variable you define in the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), to wit if you have `Status` in the Regular Expression Extractor you need to have the same in the While Controller

```
${__jexl3("${Status}" != "BatchId not found")}
```

or via [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

```
${__groovy(!vars.get('Status').equals('BatchId not found'),)}
```

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/)

Comment: Is there a possibility to prevent JMeter to not write the response message with "BatchId not found" in the result file? At the moment my loop stops as configured in the while controller, but I get also the last request message with this "BatchId not found" part.

Comment: Or can I change the response message?